# can not read from child web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My root web.config contains:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    ....
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        ....
    </appSettings>
    ....
<configuration>
```

I created another web.config file in the `~Credentials/web.config` location which contains:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="mail.smtpServer" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <add key="mail.port" value="587" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

inside my controller I am trying to access them like this:

```
private readonly string _smtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mail.smtpServer"];
private readonly int _port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mail.port"]);
```

if the mail settings are in the root `web.config` then the controller can read them but if the settings are in the child `web.config` then it can't find them, they remains null. how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an hierarchy issue. The root web config file writes the confiuguration rules of the root folder and subsequent sub folders. But the root config parameters can be overwritten by a web.config in the root of a subfolder. if your controllers are in the root folder ~credentials or in its subfolders, the child web.config can overwrite the parameters you set in the root web config.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    ....
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="mail.smtpServer" value="" />
        <add key="mail.port" value="" />
        ....
    </appSettings>
    ....
</configuration>
```

and the child web.config

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="mail.smtpServer" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <add key="mail.port" value="587" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: all my controllers are in the `~Controllers/` folder. the child web.config is in the `~Credentials/` folder and the root web.config is in the `~` root location. so i think my child web.config should work. i even tried by moving the child web.config to the `~Controllers/` folder but no luck.